# How do I retrieve multiple random rows in MySQL without an id/auto_increment column?

Tags: mysql

**My objective**

I am trying to retrieve multiple random rows that contain only unique `userid` but for the `type` column to be random - `type` can only be `0` or `1`. The table in question will contain less than 1,000 rows at any given time.

**My table**

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_message_queue (
  userid bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  messageid varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `type` int(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (userid,messageid,`type`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**Sample data**

```
userid  |   messageid   |   type
---------------------------------------------------
4353453 |   518423942   |   0
4353453 |   518423942   |   1
2342934 |   748475435   |   0
2342934 |   748475435   |   1
7657529 |   821516543   |   0
7657529 |   821516543   |   1
0823546 |   932843285   |   0
0823546 |   932843285   |   1
```

**What to rule out**

Using `ORDER BY RAND()` isn't feasible as over at least 18,000 of these types of queries are executed by applications at any given moment and are causing high load. Using `SELECT DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` is (obviously) more efficient and will always pick unique `userid` but `type` will always equal to `0` with an acceptable load.

The common method is to create an `id` column but I'm looking for an alternative way **only**. The group primary key cannot change as it is required and deeply integrated into our application, however the structure of each column can be altered.

Thanks.

Comment: Based on your sample data set, it looks like the only changing value is 'type'.  Since it's only 1 and 0, why not just do a randomize of 1 and 0 values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding of your question is that for each `userid` you have *two* entries, but want to extract only *one*, at random.

To achieve this, you ought to generate a random value between 0 and 1 for each unique `userid`, and then JOIN this list with the starting list:

```
SELECT a.* FROM tbl_message_queue AS a
    JOIN ( SELECT userid, FLOOR(2*RAND()) AS type 
           FROM tbl_message_queue GROUP BY userid ) AS b
    ON ( a.userid = b.userid AND a.type = b.type );
```

But if an `ORDER BY RAND()` does not work for you, maybe we should compromise.

In the above sequence, any two userids will be *uncorrelated* -- i.e., the fact that user A gets type 0 tells you nothing about what user B will turn up with.

Depending on the use case, a less random (but "apparently random") sequence could be obtained with two queries:

```
SELECT @X := FLOOR(2*RAND()), @Y := POW(2,FLOOR(2+14*RAND()))-1;

SELECT * FROM tbl_message_queue WHERE (((userid % @Y) & 1) XOR type XOR @X);
```

This way, you can get what seems a random extraction. What really happens is that the userids are *correlated*, and you only have some couple dozens different extractions possible. But using only simple operators, and no JOINs, this query is very fast.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt and descriptive response, it is exactly what I required and is also very efficient.